# Using asymmetric algorithm in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, encryption

I need to apply asymmetric encryption for large JSON files on client-side to transfer them to the cloud. These files can include images in the base64 format. I'm working with Angular-cli and tried to use the library crypto-browserify but can't encrypt large files. Then I tried the node-rsa library and my program works in the console, but does not work in Angular.

```js
const NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');

let key = new NodeRSA('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+
                      '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----');

let f = '{"data":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA ..."}';

let encrypt_data = key.encrypt(f, 'base64');
console.log(encrypt_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is found in using node-rsa through browserify:

browserify -r node-rsa --standalone CryptRSA > rsa-brow.js

Then added to index.html

```
<script src="assets/js/rsa-brow.js"></script>
```

Then using in Angular

```js
declare var CryptRSA: any;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    encrypt(file_content: string){
       let key = new CryptRSA(publicKey);
       let buffer = Buffer.from(file_content, 'utf-8');
       return key.encrypt(buffer, 'base64');
    }
}
```